# How to set a more specific download title in piwik

Tags: php, web-analytics, matomo

I would like to change the download display in piwik so that not the download link will appear, but the title of the download. I need this, because we use a download wrapper for rights management.
For example:

```
Instead of http://www.domain.com/download.php?id=123abc
I would like to have http://www.domain.com/Paper.doc
```

or something like that.
Does anyone have a suggestion how to realize this?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? How did you get around it?

Comment: @StephRose No, unfortunately not. I have solved it differently. The name of the download is now set in the page title. You have to use the Piwik API.
[link](http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript)